# Is it possible to delete part of a wildcard autocmd?

Tags: key-bindings, autocmd, filetype

If I put this

```
augroup AU_NAME
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorMoved *.cpp,*.hs echo localtime()
augroup END

autocmd! AU_NAME CursorMoved *.cpp
```

in my vimrc, then open a file and enter `:au AU_NAME`, I see

```
--- Autocommands ---
AU_NAME  CursorMoved
    *.hs      echo localtime()
```

i.e. the `autocmd!` deletion action was only limited to `*.cpp` files, and it did counteract part of what the `autocmd` had targeted.

However, if the `autocmd` had been `autocmd CursorMoved * echo localtime()`, then the `autocmd!` for `*.cpp` has no effect.

I think the reason is clear: the `*` pattern in `autocmd Event * ...` does not expand to a comma separated (infinite) list of patterns from which `autocmd! Group Event pattern` can subtract the pattern.

However, is there a way to accomplish the task?

---

To avoid the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), I'll give a hint of what my plan is.

With [this plugin](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap) I've created, and which I'm still refining, I create a popup on `CursorHold` showing the whole line soft-wrapped on top of itself and some lines below (a mapping is provided to dismiss the popup). The user can pass, as an option, a string, say `'*.cpp,*.html'` which I use as the pattern for the `autocmd CursorHold`. The string defaults to `'*'` to target all files.

However, I also want to give users a way to request that the popup is shown as soon as the cursor moves, i.e. on `CursorMoved` (and still be given the same mapping to dismiss it). I would let the user pass another string to use as the pattern for this `autocmd CursorMoved`.

Now it's clear that for a given file type I don't want both `CursorHold` and `CursorMoved` to create a popup. Indeed, if the user gives the options this way,

```
let g:myplugin_opts = #{ onHold: '*', onMove: '*.cpp' }
```

to mean that they want to show the popup on `CursorHold` for every filetype except for C++ file, for which they want to show popup on `CursorMoved`, I can't just use those two strings for `autocmd CursorHold` and `autocmd CursorMoved` respectively, because in C++ files both `autocmd`s would create a popup (and since I'm providing *one* `nnoremap` to close the popup by ID, it would close only one of the two popups).

Answer (score 1):

"Comma" here is simply a shortcut for two autocmds invoking same list of commands: one for `*.cpp` and another for `*.hs` patterns.

Therefore, you can't. So delete "the star" and re-create autocmd anew. Or always trap "the star" and implement all pattern checking yourself.

Comment: _implement all pattern checking yourself_ cannot be done, as I can't list all (infinite) possible extensions.

Comment: @Enlico Kidding me? Just check that extension is NOT equal to "cpp".

Comment: How d I write an `autocmd Event pattern-matching-everything-but-cpp cmd`?

Comment: @Enlico By script, not by autocmd pattern, obviously.